# Docbook 5 XSLT: Query and return value of "edition" element failing

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, docbook

I'm using docbook5 with oxygen xml editor. I'm going to PDF via XSLTproc and FOP. I am trying to get the value of the"edition" tag to show up in the footer, but this is not working correctly.

Given the docbook 5 source of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book
<book version="5.0" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" 
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
      <info>
        <title>User Manual</title>
        <edition>Ed. 123456</edition>
      </info>
</book>
```

And the footer template of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">

<xsl:template name="footer.content">  
  <xsl:param name="pageclass" select="''"/>
  <xsl:param name="sequence" select="''"/>
  <xsl:param name="position" select="''"/>
  <xsl:param name="gentext-key" select="''"/>

  <fo:block>  
    <!-- sequence can be odd, even, first, blank -->
    <!-- position can be left, center, right -->
    <xsl:choose>

      <xsl:when test="$sequence = 'odd' and $position = 'left'">  
        <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="section.head.marker"  
                        retrieve-position="first-including-carryover"
                        retrieve-boundary="page-sequence"/>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="$sequence = 'odd' and $position = 'center'">
         <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::book/info/edition"/>  
      </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The value returns properly when I query from the oxygenxml xquery section in the toolbar, but not when I process the document to PDF. Any help would be super!

Answer (score 1):

You have to take the DocBook namespace into account. By convention, the namespace URI is mapped to the `d` prefix in the stylesheets. Do this in your customization file:

1. Add

   ```
   xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" 
   exclude-result-prefixes="d"
   ```

   to the root `<xsl:stylesheet>` element.
2. Change

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::book/info/edition"/>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::d:book/d:info/d:edition"/>
   ```